# Javascript: Expected result. React: "Unexpected use of 'name' no-restricted-globals"

Tags: reactjs, keyword

I should preface this by saying that I know next to nothing about the difference between the project I started using `npx create-react-app` and the project I started using `touch app.js` `touch app.html`.

I have the following code:

```
var departments = {
  id0: "Networking",
  id1: "Video",
  id2: "Desktop PCs",
}

departments.list = function () {
  var output = "";
  for (name in departments) {
    if (typeof departments[name] == 'string') {
      output=output+departments[name].valueOf()+", ";
    }
  }
  return(output);
}
```

When I create a 'dumb' javascript app using the above-mentioned `touch` approach, invoking `departments.list()` returns `Networking, Video, Desktop PCs,` as I would expect. However, pasting this exact code into an unenclosed section of my App.js file created by `npx create-react-app` yields the compiler error `Unexpected use of 'name'  no-restricted-globals` on each line containing the word `name`.

I was under the impression that any Javascript expressions are valid in React, as React is strictly a superset of Javascript? Why does this happen? Am I wrong?

I also recognize that I'm working with a lot of systems that I don't understand, but I don't even understand them well enough to start researching them yet. Npx, npm, webpack, nodejs and their relationships to Javascript and React are all mysterious to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the `let` keyword before your `name` variable.

```
for (let name in departments) {
 ...
}
```

When you assign to an undeclared variable in JavaScript, it manipulates the global scope. If you're using strict mode, trying to assign to a undeclared variable throws an error.

More info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode/Transitioning_to_strict_mode#New_runtime_errors

Comment: Why is `let` needed in my react-app environment and not my dumb html+js environment?

Comment: Your react app is probably using strict mode which doesn't allow the use of undeclared variables. I'll add to my answer.